# An estimate for a logarithm occuring in analytic number theory

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, analytic-number-theory, estimation

Let $s$ range over the complex numbers and write such numbers as $s=\sigma+iT$ with $\sigma,T$ real. In textbooks on analytic number theory, I have found the following estimate:
$$\frac{\log|s|}{|s|} \ll \frac{\log T}{T}$$
for all $\sigma \leq -1$ and all $T\geq 2$ where the implicit constant is independent of $\sigma$ and $T$. How to rigorously prove this?

The estimate above is used in the proof of the explicit formula in the textbook on analytic number theory by Davenport as well as in the book by Montgomery and Vaughan.

Comment: All you have to show is that $log t/t$ is decreasing...

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I think it is only decreasing for $t\geq e$ but this maybe still be sufficient to make sense of the proof I am working through...